# How to uninstall Latex?

Tags: uninstall, latex

Ubuntu and Latex newbie here. Very basic question I have.

I recently installed Latex using the following code:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive
```

However, I want to uninstall this and just get the latex base for now.

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
sudo apt-get remove texlive
```

`dpkg --get-selections | grep tex` shows that a number of latex related files are installed.

How do I remove texlive?

Comment: sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove texlive*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many other dependencies also got in when you ran `sudo apt-get install texlive`. When you ran the `apt-get remove` command, then only the texlive package was uninstalled, not its dependencies.

You can easily remove these extra unneeded dependencies by running:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the explanation. I often forget that there's remove and autoremove are distinct commands.

Comment: I'd suggest to avoid the autoremove option, as if you have some broken installation of something, it can really kill all your system (It happened to me twice, I had to install Ubuntu from scratch as I had many self-compiled stuff)

Answer (score 11):

`sudo apt-get remove tex-common` resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt-get remove texlive
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get remove tex-common
```

Then download and install directly from [TUG](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html).
You can choose your operating system there.
This has a bunch of packages and is much more complete than other distributions.
Much better than `sudo apt-get install latex`.

Answer (score 2):

This removes **all** latex packages:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove texlive*
```